# how to make dataframe from indexed dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

how to create Dataframe for indexed dictionary like shown in the code below?

```
import pandas as pd
details = {
  0:{'name':'Ankit','age':'23','college':'bhu'},
  1:{'name':'Aishwarya','age':'24','college':'jnu'}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
df
```

I want table like this but it not

| name | age | college |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ankit | 23 | bhu |
| Aishwarya | 24 | jnu |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `from_dict` method, the `orient='index'` parameter tells it to use the key of the dictionary as the index of the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
details = {
  0:{'name':'Ankit','age':'23','college':'bhu'},
  1:{'name':'Aishwarya','age':'24','college':'jnu'}
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(details, orient='index')
df
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
df = pd.DataFrame(details.values())
print(df)
```

Output

```
        name age college
0      Ankit  23     bhu
1  Aishwarya  24     jnu
```

Comment: However, note that this creates a new default index.  If you want the index values to be used, I think @JihoKim's answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

Use transpose

```
import pandas as pd
details = {
  0:{'name':'Ankit','age':'23','college':'bhu'},
  1:{'name':'Aishwarya','age':'24','college':'jnu'}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(details).T
df.head()
```